# Remove AIP Protection in multi-tenant web app from SharePoint files

Tags: rest, sdk, azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection

I am trying to use `RemoveProtection` using Azure AD App in a multi-tenant web application. I am not able to figure out how. My current set-up is:

1. Registered an Azure AD app with following permissions
   [image]
2. Used following code in `IAuthDelegate`

   ```
       AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, tokenCache);
       AuthenticationResult result;

       var clientCred = new ClientCredential(appInfo.ApplicationId, clientSecret);
       result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred).Result;


       return result.AccessToken;`
   ```
3. Code in main controller

   ```
     string name = User.Identity.Name;

       // Set path to bins folder.
       var path = Path.Combine(
             Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath)).FullName,
              Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "bin\\x64" : "bin\\x86");

       MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File, path);

       ApplicationInfo appInfo = new ApplicationInfo()
       {

           ApplicationId = clientId,
           ApplicationName = appName,
           ApplicationVersion = appVersion
       };

       AuthDelegateImplementation authDelegate = new AuthDelegateImplementation(appInfo);

       var profileSettings = new FileProfileSettings(mipPath, false, authDelegate, new ConsentDelegateImplementation(), appInfo, LogLevel.Trace);

       var fileProfile = Task.Run(async () => await MIP.LoadFileProfileAsync(profileSettings)).Result;

       var engineSettings = new FileEngineSettings(name, "", "en-US");
       engineSettings.Identity = new Identity(name);

       var fileEngine = Task.Run(async () => await fileProfile.AddEngineAsync(engineSettings)).Result;
   ```

My question is how can I use it to remove AIP from a document in SharePoint?
Also, is there any REST API for this?